# Show quantity-available on inventory in broadleaf framework 5.2.x

Tags: java, inventory, broadleaf-commerce

how to show quantity-available of product in broadleaf framework?
[example is this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrTo2.png)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the field `org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.SkuImpl#quantityAvailable`. In a Thymeleaf template, assuming a Sku is on the model as 'sku', you could do something like `<span th:text="${sku.quantityAvailable}"></span>`.